# How long are moderators elected for?

Tags: support, election

I don't see this stated anywhere in the [election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) or the [main meta page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/2012-community-moderator-election).

A year?  Life?  Until StackExchange feels like it's time to have more elections?

Answer (score 7):

Elected moderators serve indefinitely unless they resign or abuse their position. From time to time, Stack Exchange may choose to hold more elections to supplement the existing moderators as the site grows.