# How does the "primary" phase of the election work?

Tags: support, election

I don't see this stated anywhere in the [election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) or the [main meta page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/2012-community-moderator-election).  Perhaps it will appear when the primary phase is entered, if it is.

None of the (analogue world) elections I participate in involve a "primary" stage, but my limited understanding of a "[primary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_election)" is that it's about picking a candidate per party.  Do we have parties here?  Is it something totally unrelated to that?

(I realise that at this point it's not looking like there will be a primary phase, although it's possible there could be two last-minute candidates).

Answer (score 1):

@Keen's [answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1336/108) for [this questio](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1335/108)n provides the answer here, too:

> In the primary phase, all nominees advance to preliminary community
>   voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the
>   primary. There is no commenting in this phase, only one up or down
>   vote per candidate. The candidate vote scores are all public. Initial
>   voting should provide a rough sense of which candidates are most
>   electable. All candidates are displayed in random order. The primary
>   is not binding; nominees may withdraw at their discretion at any point
>   during the nomination phase. After 4 days, the top 10 candidates based
>   on primary vote score proceed onward to the election phase.