# How does voting in the election work?

Tags: support, election

I don't see this stated anywhere in the [election page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election) or the [main meta page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/2012-community-moderator-election).

I suppose it'll be clear once we enter that stage, but I would like to write about this for the blog, so it would be handy to know the details now, rather than in 4 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election) link, and read the sidebar.  Looks like each tab on the election page is self-documented a little:

> In the election phase, 10 candidates advance to final community voting. Any community member with 150 reputation may vote in the election.
>
> Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, starting with the most desirable candidate first.
>
> All candidates are displayed in random order.
>
> The vote tallies are private until the election is complete.
>
> After 4 days, the final voting results will be freely downloadable from this page forever, and we will calculate the winners using OpenSTV with the Meek STV method.

Comment: Thanks.  What a non-intuitive way to put the information on the page.  I can't understand why the meta post didn't link to a page that tells you all about the elections.

Comment: @TonyMeyer I almost missed it myself when I was clicking around on the election page.